# C++ opencv face detection

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, face-recognition

I am writing a small script that should detect a face using C++, 
I develop on visual studio 2010.

the relevant methods are attached,
and I get the following exception, which I don't understand:

```
"opencvVisualization.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall cv::CascadeClassifier::~CascadeClassifier(void)" (??1CascadeClassifier@cv@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic atexit destructor for 'cascade_eye''(void)" (??__Fcascade_eye@@YAXXZ)"
```

any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include "opencvVisualization.h"
#include "main.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std; 

CvRect *r;

const string haarcascade_face = "C:\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
const string haarcascade_eye = "C:\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_eye.xml";

CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade;
CvMemStorage* storage;
CascadeClassifier cascade_face, cascade_eye;
char c;

void detectAndDisplay( IplImage* img);

void prepareCascade();

boolean isFaceImage (IplImage * image);

void prepareCascade() {
cascade = (CvHaarClassifierCascade*)cvLoad("C:\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml");
CvCapture *capture = 0;
cascade_face.load(haarcascade_face);
cascade_eye.load(haarcascade_eye);
}

boolean isFaceImage (IplImage * image) {
     CvSeq* faces = cvHaarDetectObjects(image, cascade, storage, 1.1, 3, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, cvSize (100, 100));
     int i;

    for(i = 0; i<(faces ? faces->total:0); i++)
    {

         r=(CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem(faces,i);
         cvRectangle(image,
                     cvPoint(r->x, r->y),
                     cvPoint(r->x + r->width, r->y + r->height),
                     CV_RGB(255,0,0), 1, 8, 0);
                     }
    return (i>0); 
}

/* **************************************************************************************** */
```

Comment: Could you also upload `opencvVisualization.h` as well..? It seems as though your program isn't able to recognize the class(es)/function(s) there.

Comment: are you linking opencv_objdetect ?

Comment: scap3y - it was uploaded.

Comment: also, please move over to to the c++ api, the old c one is no longer actively supported .

Comment: berak - yes. opencv_objdetect220d.lib is linked in Linker-->input-->additional dependencies (should I link some other place as well?)

Comment: You don't write **script** in C++.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved.

I removed the un-necessary CascadeClassifiers, 
and allocated memory to Storage using

```
storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
```

which was enough to run the face detection algorithm as required